# Automated deployment using CI tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am working on automated deployment of web applications using Jenkins. I am planning to provide end user with user interface that allows to choose SVN tag and enters userid and password to initiate the deployment. I would like to know, if there are any standards to follow for this job.

1. Does the automated job should include building the solution before deploying the application (or) is it ok if developer stores the result of MSBuild i.e., required binaries and SQL in the SVN TAG to just start with xcopy task.
2. If build is preferred first, how about deploying SQL scripts from SVN since it might vary build to build. And I think it might be bad idea to allow user to choose the SQL script for deployment. If by mistake, he chooses intial setup script, it might be a problem. So, how to deal with SQL deployment in this scenario to easily able to integrate with deployment process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to do nightly deployment of ASP.NET MVC 3 Website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404195/easiest-way-to-do-nightly-deployment-of-asp-net-mvc-3-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally better to build once, store the binary somewhere (e.g. NuGet) and then use it for all deployments. See

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1621865&seqNum=3

For SQL scripts you could use a db migration tool such as dbdeploy. The following article by my colleague describes the whole process with our CD tool called Go but you could easily use the information there with Jenkins.

http://lyricsoft.blogspot.in/2012/08/we-are-often-asked-about-using.html